# MATLAB working with uitab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

In working with MATLAB's `uitab`, I had two specific questions:

1. How do I remove a tab that has been created using `uitab` function?
2. How do I clear the contents of such a tab (including diagrams, buttons, etc.) without deleting the tab itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove a `uitab` from a `uitabgroup` but not delete the graphics object, you can change the `'Parent'` property to `[]`.

```
hgroup = uitabgroup();

htab = uitab(hgroup, 'Title', 'Tab');

button = uicontrol('Parent', htab, 'String', 'Button');

% Don't show the uitab
set(htab, 'Parent', []);
```

Then if you want to display the tab again, change the `'Parent'` property back to the tab group that you'd like it to belong to.

```
set(htab, 'Parent', hgroup)
```

If you want to clear a tab, you can delete all of the `'Children'` of that tab

```
delete(get(htab, 'Children'))
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another problem now. When I want to plot to the tab that I have removed the content of, nothing is displayed. (But surprisingly, the ui controls are displayed). What's the problem?

Comment: Are you creating a new `axes` object in the tab prior to trying to plot to it? If you don't, the plots will just go to the current axes which may exist somewhere else.